# Sockets Writeint error java

Tags: java, sockets

i have 3 .java 
1. Servidor
2. Cliente
3. HiloSala

Well, when i open a client , on .java servidor , accept de conection of the client and save the Socket and an Arraylist that sends the client, them, starts HiloSala method, that has to send a writeInt but i have this problem:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(Unknown Source)
    at batalla.jframes.HiloSala.atacar(HiloSala.java:54)
    at batalla.jframes.HiloSala.jugar(HiloSala.java:26)
    at batalla.jframes.HiloSala.<init>(HiloSala.java:17)
    at batalla.jframes.frmservidor.run(frmservidor.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source).
```

.Java Servidor

```
public void run(){try{

        sv = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        int i=0;
        while(true){
            while(i<2){
                sc = new Socket();
                sc = sv.accept();


                recibir=new ObjectInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                List<String>listaRecibir=(List<String>)recibir.readObject();



                nuevoCliente=new Cliente(sc,listaRecibir);
                lista.add(nuevoCliente);
                /*for(int x=0; x<listaRecibir.size();x++){
                    System.out.println(listaRecibir.get(x));
                }*/

                //System.out.println("-------");

                //sc.close();
                i++;



            }
        //sala=new HiloSala(lista.get(lista.size()-1), lista.get(lista.size()));
            sala=new HiloSala(lista.get(0), lista.get(1));
        i=0;                                        
        }           
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("no anda 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.java hiloSala

```
public HiloSala(Cliente c1, Cliente c2){
    this.c1=c1;
    this.c2=c2;
    jugar();
}


public void jugar() {
    boolean flag=true;
    while(flag){    
        atacar(c1,c2);
        System.out.println("salio");
        atacar(c2,c1);
        /*if(c1.getRecibido().size()==0 || c2.getRecibido().size()==0){
            flag=false;
        }*/         
    }
    /*
    atacar(c1,c2);
    System.out.println("salio");
    atacar(c2,c1);
    atacar(c1,c2);
    System.out.println("salio");
    atacar(c2,c1);
    */
}


public void atacar(Cliente c1, Cliente c2){
    int control=0;
    try{
        DataInputStream recibirPos; 




        DataOutputStream salidaj=new DataOutputStream(c1.getSc().getOutputStream());


        salidaj.writeInt(1); //ERROR HERE
        salidaj.flush();
        salidaj.close();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        DataOutputStream salidak=new DataOutputStream(c2.getSc().getOutputStream());
        salidak.writeInt(2);
        salidak.flush();
        salidak.close();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int estadocasilla = 0;         // 0=AGUA , 1=TOCADO/HUNDIDO
        String bufferAtacado = "";          
            DataOutputStream salidac1=new DataOutputStream(c1.getSc().getOutputStream());
            salidac1.writeInt(1);
            String posicion="";
            recibirPos=new DataInputStream(c1.getSc().getInputStream());
            posicion=recibirPos.readUTF();
            System.out.println("posicion: "+posicion);
            //ENVIANDO AL ATACANTE PARA INFORMARLE SI LE PEGO O NO AL BARCO ENEMIGO
             DataOutputStream salida=new DataOutputStream(c1.getSc().getOutputStream());
             DataOutputStream salida2=new DataOutputStream(c2.getSc().getOutputStream());

             System.out.println(c2.getRecibido().size());

            for(int i=0; i<c2.getRecibido().size();i++){

                System.out.println(c2.getRecibido().get(i));


                if(posicion.equals(c2.getRecibido().get(i))){
                    System.out.println("qweqew");
                    estadocasilla = 1;
                    salida.writeInt(estadocasilla);
                    c2.getRecibido().remove(i);
                }
            }
            if(estadocasilla==0)
                salida.writeInt(0);

            //ENVIANDO AL ATACADO PARA INFORMARLE SI LE PEGARON O NO A SU BARCO
            bufferAtacado = ""+posicion+""+estadocasilla;
            System.out.println(bufferAtacado);
            salida2.writeUTF(bufferAtacado);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            estadocasilla=0;

            salida.flush();
            salida2.flush();
            salida.close();
            salida2.close();
            ////////////////////////////////////////////


            //sv.close();

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("no anda 2");
    e.printStackTrace();}       
}
```

.java Cliente

```
    public Cliente(Socket sc, List<String> recibido){
    this.sc=sc;
    this.recibido=recibido;

}



public Socket getSc() {
    return sc;
}

public void setSc(Socket sc) {
    this.sc = sc;
}

public List<String> getRecibido() {
    return recibido;
}

public void setRecibido(List<String> recibido) {
    this.recibido = recibido;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means the other end disconnected while you are writing. This is most likely this is because you are writing as `DataOutputStream` but reading as `ObjectInputStream` which is not compatible.

BTW When you wrap a stream, I suggest you only wrap it once, otherwise this can lead to confusion.

Comment: i suppose that its waiting the message here:
public void run() {
 
 
 try{
 
 while(true){
 
 DataInputStream entrada= new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
 
 int flag=entrada.readInt();
 
 if(flag==1){
  menuataque();
 }
 if(flag==2){
  recibirAtaque(); 
 }
    
 
 entrada.close();
 }
 }catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Error conexion pidiendo tablero ataque");
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 
}``

Comment: `public void run() {
 
 
 try{
 
 while(true){
 
 DataInputStream entrada= new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
 
 int flag=entrada.readInt();
 
 if(flag==1){
  menuataque();
 }
 if(flag==2){
  recibirAtaque(); 
 }
    
 
 entrada.close();
 }
 }catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Error conexion pidiendo tablero ataque");
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 
}`

Comment: Well .. fckng shift enter this method is on frmclient that send to server

Comment: @Vanshii You also have `recibir=new ObjectInputStream(sc.getInputStream());` which means the stream can only be used for this Object stream.

Comment: Yes this stream recibes an objetinputstream, so i cannot use sc.getinputstream again ? because he is object? or i cant use recibir ?

Comment: @Vanshii the stream is state full and you can only read the data once. Some streams like OIS are buffered and will read as much data as is available. If you wrap it again you have no idea how much data you are skipping when you discard the OIS.